# How to stop MediaPlayer stream and then restart it? Android

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am making a simple app to play a online radio stream. I know how to set up the stream. Here is my code so far. It sets up the stream and plays it fine. But if I hit stop, I cannot get it to start again. Am I missing something obvious?

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

   streamButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playstopstream);

   streamButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, final boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked)
                {


                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
                else
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();



                }
            }
```

Comment: I guess I should be more clear.I want to stop the stream and then restart at the live position.

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but I came across it looking for this. Just use pause to stop, followed by seekTo(0) before restarting:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Works without having to prepare the recorder again every time.

Comment: From memory,  just start it again. You don't need to seek.

Answer (score 9):

When you call `mediaPlayer.reset()`  `mediaPlayer` goes to IDLE state.
For playback, you should do initialize to prepare before start.

You can check the mediaplayer state here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html.

Answer (score 7):

```
public void playButton (View view){

        if (isActive == false){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            isActive = true;
        }else{
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

Works OK with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, final boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            else {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be call onDestroy() medthod when finish you song / play song.
You get help from my real time code.

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public static Context context;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            // this is important.
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

            try {
                // Uri ringerUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                // getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,
                        Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
                // mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, ringerUri);

                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                if (SettingsManager.getInstance(context).getFinishCall()) {

                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        TTcall.onDestroyr();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I expected you will be helpful from above code. please try using like this. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Also you likely don't need to `stop()`, `pause()` would likely suffice, meaning that you can call `play()` once you want to continue playing.

Comment: OP wants to start over, not keep playing from where left off.

Answer (score -5):

```
mediaPlay.seek(0);
mediaPlay.pause();
```