# Return MediaController and MediaPlayer to the start of song after finish it

Tags: java, android, mediacontroller

I've created MediaPlayer with MediaControll. It works but I want to return MediaController and MediaPlayer to the start of song after finish it. So when song finished there are pause button and seek bar in the end position are still presented. I want to set seek bar to start position and change button to play(so user can click on it to replay this song) when song finished. I have the same problem with this developer: [Android MediaController End Of song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673246/android-mediacontroller-end-of-song) . I applied solution of his problem but still can't reset Controller. What's wrong in my code? As I know I should write something in `onCompletion` method.

```
 mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    controller = new MediaController(this){
        @Override
        public void show(int timeout) {
            super.show(0);
        }
    };
    listSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.release();
            }
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, arrayList.get(position).getmSongResourceId());
            mPlayer.start();
            controller.show(0);
        }
    });

    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
```

And `onCompletion` method

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.reset();
        controller.show(0);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop MediaPlayer stream and then restart it? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486951/how-to-stop-mediaplayer-stream-and-then-restart-it-android)

Comment: It is helpful, but not the same. I can start song again when it paused or finished. I just want to reset mediplayer and mediacontroller to the start of song

Comment: maybe call mPlayer.start(); after release onCompletion? )

Comment: it seems like onCompletion method doesnt work. I've tried many things, nothig happens after finish song